# OData connection to Project Online

Tags: odata, qlikview, ms-project, qliksense, ms-project-server-2013

I'm trying to establish an OData connection to our Project Online site. I'm using the link https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData, and I can connect to the OData in Excel in the following way:

1. Data -> From Other Sources -> From OData Data Feed
2. Inserting the link & choosing to use "The sign-in information for the person opening this file" as Log on credentials (i.e. using Excel's built in auth)

However, we're in a process of using the OData connection to get the data to QlikSense for reports. This is why I would like to test an account other than mine to connect to the data in Excel, but the "Use this name and password" -option as Log on credentials does not work (trying to use my Microsoft account, first.last@myorganization.com). This results in the following error:

> We couldn't connect to the data source. Please check your logon
>   information. Here's the error message we got: The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

How should the OData connection be established to Project Online, when I want to choose which credentials I want to use?

Any tips to connecting with QlikSense are welcome too, that's my end game anyway.

Comment: Does your account have the rights to access whatever you're trying to access? That's what the 403 suggests

Comment: Oh, I could've told that a little better. But anyway, when using the account with which I'm logged onto Excel (using the Excel's auth), it works. But when I'm manually trying to use that account, it doesn't. So yes, I do have the rights to access the data, and admin rights to the site, too.

Comment: Are you in a network with some kind of proxy?

Comment: No, I use the company network directly (and the site works from any network, too).